# Is this a case of omitting the Be verb? "their fins cut off""

Tags: passive-voice

I was wondering if this is a case of omitting the Be verb because I noticed the "are" was missing in the part "their fins cut off".

"Finning is a type of fishing where sharks are caught and their fins cut off".

If it's a case of omission, what is the rule for it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

> "Finning is a type of fishing where sharks are caught and their fins
> cut off".

This is indeed a case of omission.  The sentence could also have been:

> "Finning is a type of fishing where sharks are caught and their fins
> **are** cut off".

I am unsure of the full rules for when omission is possible, but basically whenever two clauses share the exact same verb or **could** share the same helping verb, the second occurrence of that verb form or helping verb may be deleted.  In this case the second occurrence of "are" is omitted.

Omission is a matter of style.  Sometimes, it improves the sentence and is normal even in casual conversation when the subject is the same and the only difference is in the predicate.  I think the particular type of omission illustrated in this question, with differences in both the subject and parts of the predicate, feels slightly more appropriate for elevated spoken or written style, unless you are clearly articulating a list of events or conditions and trying to draw attention to their similarities.  In such cases, omission might be common even in casual style.

When omission occurs, the two structures must be parallel but may differ in person or number.  For example, you can say:

> "The people are happy, and the nation content."

This sentence is fine even though the second clause omits "is," rather than "are."  Since their lexical meaning is the same and the only difference is in number [or person], the omission is fine.

However, you cannot match an irregular past tense with a combined past tense.  For instance, you **cannot** say: "*He **did go** the store and **began** to shop."  If you wanted to omit the verb, you would have to say:

"He did go the store and **begin** to shop."

Comment: Thank you very much Vegawatcher for your detailed explanations! Those are great answers and have solved my question. Thanks again.